# Array - custom foreach function

Tags: php, arrays, variables, foreach

I have an array in this form:

```
$data = array(
        array(
            'id' => '1',
            'bar' => 'foo',
            'page' => 'front',
         ),
        array(
            'id' => 'bar',
            'bar' => 'foo',
            'page' => 'front',
         ),
        array(
            'id' => 'different,
            'bar' => 'bar',
            'page' => 'back',
         ),
        array(
            'id' => 'another',
            'title' => __("Custom CSS",'solidstyle_admin'), 
            'foo' => 'bar',
            'page' => 'back',
         ),
);
```

And I want to list all ids grouped by pages and saved as variables, so if the above array is an input then output will look just like this one:

```
$front = array('1','bar');
$back = array('different','another');
//$data['page'] = array($id1, $id2, (...));
```

I was trying to do that using foreach and this is how it starts:

```
function my_output() {
     foreach($data as $something) {
        $id = $something['id'];
        $page = $something['page'];

    }
   return $output;
}
```

I was trying multiple foreach loops, and the best result I got was:

```
front = 1
front = bar
back = different
back = another
```

But I have absolutely no idea how to achieve what I want to do, I don't want anyone to do my job, just any hints? Keep in mind I'm a bit new to PHP and I don't know too much about arrays.

Thank you!

Comment: are you passing the array into your function?
ie.
`function($data){
..foreach loop
}`

...later in the code
`my_output($data);`

Comment: then you would do $foo = my_ouput($data); and then you could have access to your output through the $foo var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
$ids = array();

foreach ($data as $page) {
    $pageName = $page['page'];

    // create an empty array for your IDs
    if (!isset($ids[$pageName])) {
        $ids[$pageName] = array();
    }

    // add to the array of IDs
    $ids[$pageName][] = $page['id'];
}

var_dump($ids); // array('front' => array('1', 'bar'), ...
```

Comment: cbuckley, this looks nice but are you sure it works? For me it returns only the last elements, like `'front' => 'bar'` & `'back' => 'another'`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: change $ids[$pageName] = $page['id']; to $ids[$pageName][] = $page['id'];

Comment: Cheers @Mike, I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1):

Stick with the loop idea and do a conditional check.

```
function my_output() { 
     $front = array();
     $back = array();

     foreach($data as $something) {
        $id = $something['id'];
        $page = $something['page'];
        if ($page === 'front') {
            $front[] = $id;
        } else if ($page === 'back') {
            $back[] = $id;
        }

    }

    // Not sure what you want to return here, but you could return an array of pages

   $output = array('front' => $front, 'back' => $back); 
   return $output;
}
```

This will return something similar to:

```
$output = array(
    'front' => array(
        0 => '1',
        1 => 'bar',  
    ),
    'back' => array(
        0 => 'something',
        1 => 'another',  
    )
)
```

**Edit**: Keep in mind that my answer only accounts for the two pages you listed in your answer. If you have more pages you can also use what cbuckley's answer showed.

Comment: Looks like we went with the same answer, but I didn't want to assume that front and back were the only pages.

Comment: I noticed that when you posted your answer. Good call